# How do you create a scriban function which implements the Content Search API?

Tags: sxa, content-search, sxa-search

I've seen examples such as [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-user-object-in-scriban) on how to create a custom Scriban function.

How would I go about implementing one which supports the Content Search API like that shown [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/28602/95)?

**Example:** Function called `sc_searchitems` calls the Content Search API.

```
<h3 class="field-promotitle">{{ sc_field i_item 'PromoTitle' }}</h3>
{{ sc_field i_item 'PromoText' }}
{{ 
   queryid = "{1A5CDCC5-EBB7-49B9-8C56-7E7F74BE0C26}"
   fieldname = "Title"
}}
<ul class="items">
  {{ for i_searchitem in ( sc_searchitems i_page queryid o: "Title,Ascending" p: 50 ) }}
  <li>{{ i_searchitem.Fields[fieldname] }}</li>
  {{ end }}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this in a few steps in SXA 9.3. This approach implements the `ISearchService` included with SXA. We're basically extracting code that is used by the `SearchController`.

**Step 1** : Implement the custom search function. Add this to your `IGenerateScribanContextProcessor`.

```
private delegate IEnumerable<Item> SearchItemsDelegate(Item item, string s, string q = null, string o = null, int p = 10, int e = -1, string g = null, double r = -1);
protected ISearchService SearchService { get; } = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISearchService>();
protected ISortingService SortingService { get; } = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISortingService>();

public IEnumerable<Item> SearchItemsImpl(Item item, string s, string q = null, string o = null, int p = 10, int e = -1, string g = null, double r = -1)
{
    var siteInfo = SiteResolver.GetSiteInfo(item);
    var scopesIDs = s?.Split(',', '|').Where(ID.IsID).Select(ID.Parse);

    Coordinate center = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(g))
    {
        center = g?.Replace("|", ",");
    }

    var query = this.SearchService.GetQuery(new SearchQueryModel
    {
        Coordinates = center,
        ItemID = item?.ID,
        Query = q,
        ScopesIDs = scopesIDs
    }, out var indexName);

    var sortings = o?.Split('|').TrimAndRemoveEmpty();
    query = this.SortingService.Order(query, sortings, center, siteInfo.Name);
    if (e > 0)
    {
        query = query.Skip(e);
    }
    if (p > 0)
    {
        query = query.Take(p);
    }

    return query.Select(i => i.Uri).ToList()
        .Select(u => Factory.GetDatabase(u.DatabaseName)
            .GetItem(u.ItemID, u.Language, u.Version));
}
```

**Step 2** : Add the function to the global script object.

```
args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("sc_searchitems", new SearchItemsDelegate(SearchItemsImpl));
```

**Step 3** : Add a scriban rendering variant.

```
{{ 
   queryid = "{BBC62A76-2207-465B-BA0D-073BE71FD90C}"
   fieldname = "Title"
}}
<ul class="items">
  {{ for i_searchitem in ( sc_searchitems i_page queryid o: "Title,Ascending" p: 50 ) }}
  <li>{{ i_searchitem.Fields[fieldname] }}</li>
  {{ end }}
</ul>
```

**Note:** This version may have some missing features. If you improve upon feel free to share with me and I'll update this answer.

**Update:** You may have noticed that at the end of the code where the items are pulled from the search engine that `Uri` is selected. In my experience I've found that the SXA search can be made significantly faster by selected just the `Uri` from the search engine and then getting items based on that property. A feature request would be for SXA to do the same by default.