# VelocityContext in Sitecore 10.1

Tags: sxa, nvelocity

When migrating from Sitecore 8.2 to 10.1. I have encountered the error in VelocityContext

This is the code.

```
public class AddTemplateRenderers : IGetTemplateRenderersPipelineProcessor
{
    public void Process(GetTemplateRenderersPipelineArgs args)
    {
        args.Context.Put("linkTool", new LinkTool());
        args.Context.Put("fieldTool", new FieldTool());
    }
}
```

We used this link(https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2018/10/23/Sitecore-SXA-Using-Placeholders-with-NVelocity-Templates/) in Sitecore 8.1 to create the class

There is no Sitecore.NVelocity dll for Sitecore 10.1.

Is there any alternate for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NVelocity has been completely and totally removed. SXA has adopted Scriban as a replacement.

I believe this was introduced in 9.3:
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/scriban-templates.html

[Example building a custom function](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/28748/95)