# How to use orderby in Scriban template?

Tags: sxa, scriban

I have to list my upcoming events on the web page. I have created the data source item for holding all the events and each event has event date. I'm using Scriban to display all the events. My question is how should I ignore the passed day events and have to do the order by event date.

This is my Scriban Code snippet:

```
<div>
         {{ for i_child in i_datasource.children }}
             <div> 
               <h1><a href="{{ sc_link_url i_child 'CTA'}}"> {{ sc_field i_child 'Title'}}</a></h1>
             </div>     
       {{ end }}
    
</div>
```

**Finally Done**

As mentioned here [How do you create a scriban function which implements the Content Search API?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28748/how-do-you-create-a-scriban-function-which-implements-the-content-search-api) I have created the new search method for my requirements.

**Created new class file**

```
 public class GetSortOrder : IGenerateScribanContextProcessor
{
    protected ISearchService SearchService { get; }
    protected ISortingService SortingService { get; }
    protected ISiteInfoResolver SiteInfoResolver { get; }

    public GetSortOrder(ISearchService searchService, ISortingService sortingService)
    {
        SearchService =searchService;
        SortingService = sortingService;
    }
    private delegate IEnumerable<Item> SearchItemsDelegate(Item item, string s, string q = null, string o = null, int p = 10, int e = -1, string g = null, double r = -1);
  

   /// <summary>
    /// Search API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">ScopeID</param>
    /// <param name="p">NumberOfResults</param>
    /// <param name="o">Order</param>
    /// <param name="f">OrderBy FieldName</param>
    /// <returns>Result Items</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Item> SearchItemsImpl(string s, int p = 10, int o = 0, string f = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var scopesIDs = s?.Split(',', '|').Where(ID.IsID).Select(ID.Parse);

            var query = this.SearchService.GetQuery(new SearchQueryModel
            {
                ScopesIDs = scopesIDs,
            }, out var indexName);

            //if o=1 then ascending
            if (o == 1)
                query = query.OrderBy((ContentPage i) => i.get_Item<double>((string)f));
            else
                query = query.OrderByDescending((ContentPage i) => i.get_Item<double>((string)f));

            if (p > 0)
            {
                query = query.Take(p);
            }

            return query.Select(i => i.Uri).ToList()
                .Select(u => Factory.GetDatabase(u.DatabaseName)
                    .GetItem(u.ItemID, u.Language, u.Version));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("SearchItemsImpl-error-{0}stacktrace{1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString()), ex);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void Process(GenerateScribanContextPipelineArgs args)
    {
        args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("sc_searchitems", new SearchItemsDelegate(SearchItemsImpl));
    }
}
```

**Added in Patch file**

```
   <processor type="Foundation.ScribanExtensions.Pipelines.GetSortOrder, Foundation.ScribanExtensions" resolve="true" />
```

**Updated scriban**

```
{{ for i_searchitem in ( sc_searchitems i_datasource "{D7C469EF-8B47-4B19-810F-3ACA1354D979}" o: "EventDate,Descending" p: 50 q:"./*[@@templatename='Events'] " ) }}
  <li>{{ i_searchitem.Fields['Title'] }}</li>
{{ end }}
```

Here, I have mentioned my field EventDate, not working. I could see, it is working as expected with Title Field. So, something i have to add for Date field, s

Comment: Similar to this answer here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28748/how-do-you-create-a-scriban-function-which-implements-the-content-search-api you can consider writing a custom function to sort exactly how you want.

Comment: @MichaelWest Thank you for your quick response. Do you have a GitHub URL for the code file? I am facing issue with the namespace, if  I received it would helpful to me

Comment: The example I provided is something you would incorporate into your solution.

Comment: You should indeed create your own function for logic like this.

Comment: @MichaelWest the given code is working fine. Thank you. I am trying to do the sorting using the EventDate field, but it's not working. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: At the bottom of your original question, can you add an updated section where you provide your current progress? You could reference whatever materials you used and a code snippet to show what you have working. This will help provide further guidance.

Comment: @MichaelWest I have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: @MichaelWest Thank you so much for your help, finally everything is working and updated my code as well

Comment: @MichaelWest is there any possibility to make this field as editable in experience editor?

Comment: You'll want to open a new question with all the appropriate details for that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and would like to post the

```
   public IEnumerable<Item> SearchItemsImpl(string s, int p = 10, int o = 0, string of = null, string f = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var scopesIDs = s?.Split(',', '|').Where(ID.IsID).Select(ID.Parse);

            var query = this.SearchService.GetQuery(new SearchQueryModel
            {
                ScopesIDs = scopesIDs,
            }, out var indexName);

            //if o=1 then ascending
            if (o == 1)
                query = query.OrderBy((ContentPage i) => i.get_Item<double>(of));
            else
                query = query.OrderByDescending((ContentPage i) => i.get_Item<double>(of));

            //filter by passed date
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
                query = query.Where((ContentPage i) => i.get_Item<DateTime>(f) >= DateTime.Now);

            if (p > 0)
            {
                query = query.Take(p);
            }

            return query.Select(i => i.Uri).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(u => Factory.GetDatabase(u.DatabaseName)
                    .GetItem(u.ItemID, u.Language, u.Version));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("SearchItemsImpl-error-{0}stacktrace{1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString()), ex);
        }
        return new List<Item>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering question from the title of your question, there are built-in functions for array in scriban:

- array.sort ( https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/builtins.md#arraysort )
- array.reverse ( https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/builtins.md#arrayreverse )

How you can use it in Sitecore? Something like that normally would do the trick if you want to order by item `Name` descending:

```
for i_child in i_datasource.children | array.sort "Name" | array.reverse
```

And then you can compare

```
if (i_child.Name > "b")
```

But I don't think there is an option to do the same with dates easily. If you try to compare

```
if (i_child.EventData > data.now)
```

I expect that you will get some error from scriban. Also, don't think that sorting would work for you with date field.

Comment: I just tried the first one. I am facing this issue

for i_child in i_datasource.children | array.sort "Name"
-------------
Failed to compare two elements in the array.